# How to call a cloud function via the node.js cloud sdk from an AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sdk

I want to call an Google Cloud Function from an AWS Lambda. I did this already using the URL of the function (which needs no authentication), but now I want to call the function with authentication and I thought the Cloud SDK could help me achieving this.

I found [this](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/nodejs-functions/latest/google.cloud.functions.v1.CallFunctionRequest.html#.create) function here, but I am not sure how to use it and if I can use it from an AWS Lambda? And if this is not possible, what are the alternatives? Using the API Gateway?

Happy to hear some experiences here! :)

Comment: Google cloud functions provide you url to call the function. You can use it in your aws lambda

Comment: Thanks! I know this already, but I wanted to know if there are other options like using the Google Cloud SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I have some good news for you, you can enable the use the URL of you function with autenthication. This are the steps:

1. Visit [google cloud consle](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Click in the Navigation Menu
3. Click on Cloud Functions
4. Select your cloud function
5. An option called permissions will appear in the top menu
6. In the filter write: allUsers and then click on delete (if you can't find this option, this url is currently required authentication) also find allAuthenticatedUsers and delete if there is present.
7. Then I recomment to you read the following documention to know how to make [authenticating function-to-function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function)