# How to call an HTTP cloud function using Python in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send JSON data from AWS S3 to a google cloud function, through a lambda function (Python). A JSON file being added to S3 will trigger the lambda function, which will execute a POST event that sends the contents of the JSON file to a google cloud function.

I know that it is possible because it is referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518623/how-to-call-a-cloud-function-via-the-node-js-cloud-sdk-from-an-aws-lambda#comment117619531_66518623) post, but there is no explanation or code to give me a start.

I know how to set up a lambda function, but I don't know how to make a POST event to send data to the URL of a cloud function. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's a simple HTTP call. No more. The underlying platform doens't change the nature of the communication. Or your problem is elsewhere. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your cloud function is an `onRequest` type as you cannot invoke an `onCall` without the Firebase modules.

onRequest example:

```js
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
  // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});
```

How to invoke a cloud function:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function